# Android Widget PendingIntent Fails

Tags: android

There have been some similar issues discussed here, but my situation does work some of the time. I am developing a widget that when clicked should launch an activity that's part of the same package. This same activity can also be launched by a notification that may be posted. The widget updates and notification posting are done by a Service in the package. Here is the method that's called to issue the PendingIntent:

```
// Get pending intent for widget or notification
private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(int widgetId, int extraData) {
    Intent clickIntent = new Intent(mCtx, OtdShowEvents.class);
    clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
    clickIntent.putExtra("OTDExtra", extraData);
    clickIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mCtx, 0, clickIntent, 
            0);
    return pendIntent;
}
```

If I create an instance of the widget on a clean (rebooted) device, both the widget and notification launch the target activity as expected. However, if I remove the widget and create another instance, the Intent is no longer launched. Likewise, if I uninstall the widget altogether, then re-install it and create an instance, no Intent is fired off. However, if I power off and back on (leaving the widget in place), it works again when booted up.

One error that I saw along the way was from the PackageManager saying "Name not found", but indicating the package name "com.ghcssoftware.OTD.full", which is the correct name of my package!

Any ideas? And by the way, I have tried some of the PendingIntent flags such as FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT and FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT without affecting this behavior.

FWIW, I found that the code snippet provided in this article was exactly what I needed to figure out how to get this all working correctly, especially for multiple instances of my widget, etc.: [PendingIntent in Widget + TaskKiller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706303/pendingintent-in-widget-taskkiller)